# SonarQube - Multimodule project based on filesystem hierarchy

Tags: sonarqube

Some cvsrepository named Foo has several modules, f.e. module1, module2, ...
A buildscript does cvs checkout, compile and building the module.jar for all modules.
After the build has finished the filesystem looks like that :

```
Foo/module1/src
           /bin
   /module2/src
           /bin
   ...
```

Now i want to use the sonartask like that :
Define the global sonar properties like sonar.username ... sonar.projektName=Foo for MainProject and sonar.modules=module1.module2,... for the modules.
Afterwards looping over the module folders, setting module specific sonar properties,
like sonar.projectName (for modulename) sonar.sources, sonar.binaries etc.
Looping works fine, but it seems as sonar wants a single build.xml for every submodule.
So i need another possibility for grouping modules.
I only found a commercial plugin => [Portfolio Management plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/) but need another solution.

**-- EDIT --**

I already found and tried to use the examples from [github](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/ant) and [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeAntTask-Multi-moduleProject), but it seems they
require one main build file and a build.xml in every module folder.
Whereas my situation is different. There's only one build.xml that contains a javac + jar target for every module of my project. When build is done, the resulting filesystem looks like mentioned above.
The build is part of the deployment workflow which is driven by a xmlproperty file, that contains the projectname and all modulenames of that deployment job among other things.
Now after the build is done, in the next antfile i want to loop over the modules in that xmlproperty file via xmltask, pointing the module specific properties to filesystem, f.e. sonar.sources=/Foo/module1/src sonar.binaries=/Foo/module1/bin and call `<sonar:sonar/>` . Overriding of module specific properties in the loop is done via [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) `<let>`
After all it's just looping over an existing filesystem setting the sonar poperties and calling the sonar task with approiate properties.
**-- EDIT after comment --**
Tried it like that :
build.xml

```
<project name="sonar" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
  <fl:install-property-handler/>

  <!-- Import Sonar -->
  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml"/>

  <!-- Import XMLTask -->
  <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

  <xmltask source="C:/WKS/Eclipse/372/sonar/props.xml">
    <copy path="//project/name/text()" property="projectname"/>
    <copy path="//module/*/label/text()" property="projectlabel"/>
    <copy path="//module/*/name/text()" property="modules" append="true" propertyseparator="," />
  </xmltask>

  <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${projectname}"/>

  <!-- Set modules IDs -->
  <property name="sonar.modules" value="#{replace('${modules}', '', ' ')}"/>

  <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
  <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://somehost:9000" />
  <property name="sonar.login" value="admin" />
  <property name="sonar.password" value="admin" />

  <xmltask source="C:/WKS/Eclipse/372/sonar/props.xml">
    <call path="//module/*">
      <param path="label/text()" name="modullabel"/>
      <param path="name/text()" name="modulname"/>
      <actions>
        <fl:let>
          sonar.projectName ::= replace('@{modulname}', '', ' ')
          sonar.projectVersion ::= '@{modullabel}'
          sonar.#{replace('@{modulname}', '', ' ')}.projectBaseDir ::= '${ant.working.dir}/build/projects/${projectname}/@{modulname}'
          sonar.sources ::=  '${ant.working.dir}/build/projects/${projectname}/@{modulname}/src'
          sonar.binaries ::= '${ant.working.dir}/build/results/compile/${projectname}/@{modulname}'
        </fl:let>
        <!-- Execute Sonar -->
        <sonar:sonar />
      </actions>
    </call>
  </xmltask>
</project>
```

output :

```
Setting project property: modules -> Modul 1,Modul 2,Modul 3,Modul 4
Setting project property: sonar.projectKey -> Foobar
Setting project property: sonar.modules -> Modul1,Modul2,Modul3,Modul4
Setting project property: ant.working.dir -> c:\WKS\5513
Setting project property: sonar.language -> java
Setting project property: sonar.sourceEncoding -> UTF-8
Setting project property: sonar.host.url -> http://somehost:9000
Setting project property: sonar.login -> admin
Setting project property: sonar.password -> admin
Setting project property: sonar.projectName -> Modul1
Setting project property: sonar.projectVersion -> l_5_04_52_cd
Setting project property: sonar.Modul1.projectBaseDir -> c:\WKS\5513/build/projects/foobar/Modul 1
Setting project property: sonar.sources -> c:\WKS\5513/build/projects/foobar/Modul 1/src
Setting project property: sonar.binaries -> c:\WKS\5513/build/results/compile/foobar/Modul 1
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/WKS/Eclipse/372/DevJars/sonar/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/WKS/Eclipse/372/DevJars/sonar/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Class org.sonar.ant.SonarTask loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013
[sonar:sonar] Sonar Ant Task version: 2.1
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/WKS/Eclipse/372/DevJars/sonar/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Work directory: C:\WKS\sonar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Sonar Server 3.7.2

BUILD FAILED
C:\WKS\Eclipse\372\sonar\sonar.xml:41: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\WKS\Eclipse\372\sonar\sonar.xml:54: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The base directory of the module 'Modul1' does not exist: C:\WKS\Eclipse\372\sonar\Modul 1
```

I tried also to set the basedir attribute to the value of my ${ant.working.dir}, where all binariues and src folders reside, didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

See documentation : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeAntTask-Multi-moduleProject

And example : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/ant

Comment: Thanks, already found that, but it didn't work for me, see --EDIT-- in my answer.

Comment: In that case, if you want to configure everything in a single configuration file you can also take a look to the following examples : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/sonar-runner. There are based on SonarRunner but you can do exactly the same thing in the Sonar Ant task.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, already tried in that direction, see second -- EDIT-- but it didn't work.

Comment: both links are now dead. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. When you run the ant task from eclipse, sonar errors are not showed. so, I figure out the problem when the ant ask was executed from command console.

I had two problems:

1. The sonar.host.url property is mandatory
2. The sonar.projectKey could not contain special characters, for instance space